# the "size on disk" of my WUBI folder is smaller than the "size"

Tags: windows-7

I am really surprised to find that the "Size on disk" for a folder on my machine is way less than the "Size" value. Any idea why this might be?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Windows can transparently **compress** files (using a variant of LZ77) before storing them to disk, if using the NTFS filesystem.

In addition, a file can be marked as [**sparse**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148159.aspx) – if a large part of the file is empty (consists entirely of null bytes), Windows will not store them on disk; it'll just mark the entire part as being a "hole".

In addition, Explorer is not known for its accuracy. See the article [Just What Is ‘Size on Disk’?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148159.aspx) on TechNet.

Comment: It's interesting that Wubi would choose to use eiter sparse or compressed file for the disk image, as it can make disk I/O on the guest OS a bit slower...

Comment: Lazer can easily check if compression is being used as any compressed files will be coloured blue in the Explorer directory listing.

Comment: Is that colouring on by default?

Comment: @grawity The default is to use colour for encrypted (green) and NTFS compressed (blue) files on Vista and WIndows 7. I can't remember if the option was off or on by default in XP. The option can be chosen on the View tab of Folder options: Show encrypted or compressed NTFS files in color.